# React router dom params issue

Tags: reactjs, parameters, react-router-dom

I tried to Routing the params ":id" in react with a sub Route ":id/history" and the route link not render the component on clicking

```
<Switch>
     <Route path="/patients/:id" exact component={GeneralData} />
     <Route path="/patients/:id/history" component={History} />
</Switch>
```

Comment: Hi Siddharta, I just wrote you an answer, let me know if that clears things up for you :)

Comment: done! the problem is at parent switch, i had the same order at Route's, thanks dude!

Comment: You're welcome bro! Happy coding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Switch` component renders the first route that matches the URL you entered

Because you are using a wildcard for your `GeneralData` Route like so

```
<Route path="/patients/:id" component={GeneralData}/>
```

No matter what you enter after `/patients`, it gets captured in that wildcard definition of that Route because it accepts literally anything. So even if you navigate to `/patients/4834834/history` it still satisfies the `GeneralData` route which was found first in the list of routes.

To fix this, simply move your History Route above your GeneralData Route. This makes it so the `GeneralData` route will not get rendered for anything that just satisfies `/patients/:id`. `Switch` will look to see if your URL matches `History` first.

```
<Switch>
     <Route path="/patients/:id/history" component={History} />
     <Route path="/patients/:id" component={GeneralData} />
</Switch>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're omitting `exact` param.

Comment: Can you try in this order "<Route exact  path...".